# Secure Way to Handle Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Credentials in Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, credentials

I am currently using Apache Airflow to orchestrate my DAGs and I am testing my program locally. In my code, I have a function that requires a Google Cloud connection to provide identity tokens to my Airflow tasks. Here is the function:

```
def get_identity_token(service_url):
    creds, project = google.auth.default()
    auth_req = Request()
    token = id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, service_url)
    return token
```

Currently, I am setting the GCP credentials in the code like this:

`os.environ[ "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" ] = "xxxx/xxxxx.json"`

I am looking for a more secure way to manage these credentials. I was thinking of loading the JSON credentials into an environment variable directly through the Airflow UI, but I'm unsure if this is the best approach. I'm open to suggestions on better methods for securely handling these credentials.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If applicable you can try [SA impersonation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-overview#impersonation) by adding a user to a principal of a service account.

Good references for service account impersonation: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions

Also it appears that apache airflow has an operator example for this: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions